# Did small rural newspaper offices in 1895 use rotary presses with rolls of paper or sheets?

Tags: united-states, media, printing

I'm trying to find out what kind of press would have been used for the Troutdale Champion in Troutdale, Oregon (population 300), which printed for a few years in the mid 1890s. After researching some, I'm thinking they used something like the Washington Iron Hand Press. Finding out for sure will be easier when everything is open once again and I can visit historical societies.

Comment: Hello Karen! So there's no mis-communication, perhaps you could define the "small" rural place?

Comment: Gestenter perhaps for limited number of copies : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gestetner

Comment: I'm writing about a town of 400 people in rural western Oregon in 1897.  I'm sure there's no Gestetner machine then but would such a paper even have a mechanical press?

Comment: Have you been able to identify the names of any actual historical newspapers from the approximate time and place you are interested in?

Comment: Please edit all clarifications of the question  into the original post. Questions must stand alone, as all comments are ephemeral, subject to arbitrary deletion at any time.

Answer (score 2):

There were a host - literally - of [newspapers published in Oregon](https://oregonnews.uoregon.edu/newspapers/) starting in 1846, some even continuing to the current day. The [East Oregonian](https://oregonnews.uoregon.edu/lccn/sn88086023/) is an example of one still publishing that began publishing on [Thursday March 1, 1888,](https://oregonnews.uoregon.edu/lccn/sn88086023/1888-03-01/ed-1/seq-1/) apparently on broadsheet.

[image]

By contrast [The Stayton Sun](https://oregonnews.uoregon.edu/lccn/sn00063612/) was a considerably more modest effort, publishing [exactly one issue on December 19, 1889](https://oregonnews.uoregon.edu/lccn/sn00063612/1889-12-19/ed-1/)

[image]

The wide variety and great number of early papers strongly suggests that one cannot make broad assumptions about them all, but must rather consider the specific circumstances of each particular publisher and community.

Comment: Thanks, Peter.  I'm thinking specifically  of the Troutdale Champion in Troutdale, Oregon (population 300), which printed for a few years in the mid 1890s. After researching some more, I'm thinking they used something like the Washington Iron Hand Press.  Finding out for sure will be easier when everything is open once again.